# Is Blazemeter a plugin of Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, open-source, blazemeter

Is Blazemeter a plugin of JMeter?

If yes, how can I go through the blazemeter code as JMeter is open source?

If no, How does it supports JMeter scripts?

Also, how blazemeter records without certs? what changes it performs to browser settings for recording without certs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/about) is a Computer Associates company which:

- has offers **paid** solutions for testing.

  > SaaS, Cloud and on-premise continuous testing solution
- created open source solutions as [taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/about)
- partly sponsors and contributes to [JMeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org),
- contribute sometimes patches to open source projects as [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org)

Comment: Thanks! what about recording hsts web apps without certificates?

Comment: It uses blazemeter certificate https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-?mobile_site=true

Comment: Blazemeter app uses mitmproxy server and blazemeter certs. But what about the chrome extension? It must be configuring in chrome to record using the extension. Or it just like a network sniffer that sniffs requests?